# Android virtual device cannot start on Windows 7

Tags: android-studio

Whenever I try to create a virtual device in `Android Studio` it always returns this error:

```
Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings.
```

I have installed `haxm 6.1.2` and it's not working. My computer is with Intel Core i5-2450m CPU.  From Intel's website, it shows that it supports virtualization. But I have not been able to figure out how to enable the virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

I think the virtualization isn't enabled in your BIOS settings.
Open boot menu by pressing F2 just before your system starts. Go to System Security. Make sure that VIRTUAL TECHNOLOGY VTX is checked, then hit F10 to save.

I hope this will work.